# He said,"I am going to New York tomorrow." Into indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

He said,"I am going to New York tomorrow." Into indirect speech.
How do I do this question? Should I change 'am going' to 'was going' or to 'would be going'

Comment: am going to > was going to, will be going to > would be going to. You may ask this type of question on the link above (from Cascabel)

Comment: 'Tomorrow' needs to change also. Your alternatives are 'virtually synonymous' , though there may be some strange archaic law of conversion.

Comment: I believe the correct sentence could look like this : "He said, he would be going to New York the next day".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to think of reported speech as a description of what was meant, rather than a mechanical conversion from direct quote.  When you understand it like this you see that "I'm going to New York tomorrow" and "I will go to New York tomorrow" and "I will be going to New York" mean the same thing.

So when reported you could use either

> He said he was going to New York

or

> He said he would be going to New York

both report the same fact.

There is no need to use the original words. You can report the fact in many ways:

> He told me that he was taking a trip to the Big Apple

But for the sake of tests of English.  You backshift "am going" to "was going".  You also need to deal with "tomorrow" because "tomorrow" when he said it, might be something different.

> He said he was going to New York [tomorrow].

Comment: It sounds quite confusing.